# A card is drawn at random from a standard 52-card deck. The conditional probability that the card is a 2 given that a 2 or a 3 is drawn is

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

The answer is 1/2, but I'm really confused with the part that says "given that a 2 or a 3 was drawn".

How did 1/2 come about?

Comment: Can you answer this variation?  "A card is drawn at random from a deck in which all but the twos and threes have been removed--that is, it is an eight-card deck with four twos and four threes.  What is the probability that the drawn card is a two?"

Comment: It seems this might be a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 2):

There are the same number of 3's in the deck as there are 2's (i.e. both have 4 chances to be drawn). So if you know that a 2 or a 3 was drawn, then the chance of one vs. the other must be the same. As the probabilities of the two cases must sum to one, then each must be 1/2.

Comment: I was in the middle of typing... otherwise, I wouldn't have started after seeing your answer pop up... +1

Answer (score 2):

Just think of the denominator in the calculations involved.

What the wording "given that" indicates in probability is a [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability). It restricts the sample space.

In general you would have a probability of drawing a $2$ of $\frac{4}{52}=\frac{1}{13}$.

But say that someone has peeked and been allowed to provide the added information that the card is either a $2$ or a $3$. Well, now any other possibilities are ruled out (for example, a queen or an ace). The denominator has shrunken to only four $2$'s and four $4$'s. So you end up with a probability of $\frac{4}{8}=\frac{1}{2}.$